# EF Core 2.0 Identity - Adding navigation properties

Tags: c#, mysql, postgresql, entity-framework-core

In EF Core 2.0 Identity navigation properties are not included by default, so after upgrading,  I added them. So for Many-To-Many relationship between User and Role, and One-To-Many relationship between Role and RoleClaim, I added following navigation properties:

```
public class User : IdentityUser
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityUserRole<string>> Roles { get; set; }
}

public class Role : IdentityRole
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<IdentityRoleClaim<string>> Claims { get; set;}
}
```

Surprisingly it adds an additional `RoleId1` key to `AspNetRoleClaims` table and `UserId1` to `AspNetUserRoles` tables and all the get queries actually use new keys instead of `RoleId` and `UserId` which are also present.

Comment: See the answer on this thread https://stackoverflow.com/a/47772406/82197

Answer (score 11):

I do not know why, there are not these useful navigation properties. I want to list users with their roles.

So I did the follow:

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; } = new List<ApplicationUserRole>();
}

public class ApplicationUserRole : IdentityUserRole<string>
{
    public virtual ApplicationUser User { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationRole Role { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationRole : IdentityRole<string>
{
    public ApplicationRole(){ }

    public ApplicationRole(string roleName)
        : base(roleName)
    {
    }

    public virtual ICollection<ApplicationUserRole> UserRoles { get; } = new List<ApplicationUserRole>();
}
```

This creates the navigation, but it creates additional columns like `RoleId1` and `Discriminator`. So, I added the following according to [Add IdentityUser POCO Navigation Properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/1x-to-2x/identity-2x#add-identityuser-poco-navigation-properties).

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
{
    base.OnModelCreating(builder);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
        .HasMany(e => e.UserRoles)
        .WithOne()
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId)
        .IsRequired()
        .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>()
        .HasOne(e => e.User)
        .WithMany(e => e.UserRoles)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.UserId);

    builder.Entity<ApplicationUserRole>()
        .HasOne(e => e.Role)
        .WithMany(e => e.UserRoles)
        .HasForeignKey(e => e.RoleId);
}
```

But I still have both columns `RoleId1` and `Discriminator`. After that, I replace with the new ApplicationRole class in ApplicationDbContext, DI configuration service and DB seed.

```
public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole, string, IdentityUserClaim<string>
    , ApplicationUserRole, IdentityUserLogin<string>, IdentityRoleClaim<string>, IdentityUserToken<string>>
{
    ...
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
   ...
   services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, ApplicationRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
   ...
}

public DbInitializer(
        ApplicationDbContext context,
        UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager,
        RoleManager<ApplicationRole> roleManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
        _roleManager = roleManager;
    }

public async void Initialize()
    {
        _context.Database.EnsureCreated();

        if (!_context.Roles.Any(r => r.Name == SharedConstants.Role.ADMINISTRATOR))
            await _roleManager.CreateAsync(new ApplicationRole(SharedConstants.Role.ADMINISTRATOR));
    }
```

Also, I could navigate and get the first name of role.

```
ctx.Users.Select(e => new
            {
                e.Id,
                e.UserName,
                e.Email,
                e.PhoneNumber,
                Roles = e.UserRoles.Select(i => i.Role.Name).ToList()
            }).ToList();
```

I hope this give you a clue for `Claims` navigation property.

Comment: Thanks for the very thorough answer.  I just hit up against this, followed your advice, and it's good to go now!

Answer (score 7):

I've encountered the same issue, in my case the problem was caused because I had put the call to `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` at the bottom of `OnModelCreating`. Moving `base.OnModelCreating(builder)` at the very top solved the issue (no duplicate columns and FKs).

[image]

Thanks to this [GitHub issue](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFrameworkCore/issues/9503#issuecomment-431318312)

Comment: This solved the issue for me.  @UUHHIVS has a good answer for 'set-up'.  However, this answer above is what solved my issue ^^

Comment: Old topic but solved my problem as well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I encountered with same issue and this is solution.

You have to tell Ef on which navigation property you are going to have OneToMany Relation.

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);


        CreateUserModel(modelBuilder.Entity<User>());
        CreateRoleModel(modelBuilder.Entity<Role>());

    }


    private void CreateRoleModel(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        entityTypeBuilder.HasMany(role => role.UserRoles).
            WithOne(**e=> e.Role**).
            HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.RoleId).
            IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }

    private void CreateUserModel(EntityTypeBuilder<User> entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        entityTypeBuilder.HasMany(user => user.UserRoles).
            WithOne(**e=>e.User**).
            HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.UserId).
            IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
```

You can Also specify navigation property in string like

```
private void CreateRoleModel(EntityTypeBuilder<Role> entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        entityTypeBuilder.HasMany(role => role.UserRoles).
            WithOne(**"Role"**).
            HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.RoleId).
            IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }

    private void CreateUserModel(EntityTypeBuilder<User> entityTypeBuilder)
    {
        entityTypeBuilder.HasMany(user => user.UserRoles).
            WithOne(**"User"**).
            HasForeignKey(userRole => userRole.UserId).
            IsRequired()
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
    }
```