# Integrating built-in User Authentication with a Code-First Database

Tags: c#, authentication, asp.net-core

I'm unsuccessfully reading and fighting with the idea how to properly build a simple MVC web application. There are many tutorials but each one sucks, I mean they show how to add simple type fields to `ApplicationUser` and use them in `AccountViewModel` and `ManageViewModel`. What I need is using custom objects, not simple fields.

I made a simple solution for testing. I try to implement **One-to-one** (UserProfile - Address) relationship.

Here is my **ApplicationUser.cs** class:

```
namespace DBRelationsTesting.Models
{
    // Add profile data for application users by adding properties to the ApplicationUser class
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public virtual AddressViewModel Address { get; set; }
        public virtual ICollection<PhotoGalleryViewModel> PhotoGallery { get; set; }
    }
}
```

**AddresViewModel** class:

```
namespace DBRelationsTesting.Models.AccountViewModels
{
    public class AddressViewModel
    {
        [Key]
        public int AddressId { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string Country { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Consequently I created the database class `AddressViewModel`, updated the Views, added `DbSets` and modified the Controllers.

All I got was that the database is being filled with **foreign key data** but I can't get the **foreign key fields** to be displayed in Views.
From what I read this is some safety limitation of User Authentication. Is it true?

In a separate testing project I tried making the same but not in the User Authentication classes and after using the `Include()` function in the Controller It works(on the example of Details action). It fills the foreign class fields.

```
// GET: UserProfiles/Details/5
public async Task<IActionResult> Details(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    var userProfile = await _context.UserProfile
        .Include(usrProfile => usrProfile.Address)
        .SingleOrDefaultAsync(m => m.UserProfileID == id);
    if (userProfile == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return View(userProfile);
}
```

Why in `ManageController`(in the project with Authentication) can't I use `Include()`?

In this case how can I link my custom classes with the User Authentication system so that the logged in user won't see other users data?
Should I add the built-in User object in my custom `UserProfile` class like below? Will it work?

```
public virtual User User { get; set; }
```

Comment: What *exactly* do you mean by "Why in ManageController (in the project with Authentication) can't I use Include()?"? What specific method(s) are you using to get the user?

Comment: On a side note: that `Address` is not a ViewModel, that's a database entity. Entity => represents the database table, ViewModel => an adaptation of the entity that a View uses

Comment: Thanks for clarifying the conception of ViewModel.
``

Comment: In line:
`var user = await _userManager.GetUserAsync(User);`
I tried to add Address with Include() property but it is not seen in this context. Perhaps because of the security restricions in Authentication.

Comment: Ahh, that's what you mean. No, you cannot use `Include` because that's not a LINQ query. Read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767267)