# How to use LINQ for Link tables?

Tags: c#, linq, razor

I am working on a webapp in razor pages using .net core 2. I implemented the standard individual accounts and I am able to work with the data.

However, I'd like to extend my dashboard by displaying the users with its corresponding role.

I have these tables:

### mssql

```
AspNetUsers
UserId | Email | Password | Etc

AspNetRoles
RoleId | RoleName

AspNetUserRoles
UserId | RoleId
```

### users.cshtml.cs

```
private readonly ApplicationDbContext _dbContext;

public List<ApplicationUser> users { get; set; }

public UsersModel(ApplicationDbContext dbContext)
{
    _dbContext = dbContext;
}

public async void OnGet()
{
    users = _dbContext.Users.ToList();
}
```

When I loop use `@foreach(var user in @Model.users`, I can only (ofcourse) access the columns of the `AspNetUsers`-table.

I'd like to query over all my users and use user.Role for example.

I am aware of this solution

```
  var admins = _userManager.GetUsersInRoleAsync("Admin").Result;
```

But I don't want to repeat myself a couple of times. Everything needs to be dynamic. And I'd like to change this role, since I have to be able to edit it later on.

So, my concrete question is: how can I accomplish the following situation based on my current database structure and code by using LINQ?

### My ideal situation

```
// my .cshtml
<table>
    <tbody>
         @foreach(var user in @Model.users)
         {
             <tr>@user.Name - @user.Role</tr>
         }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

#### edit 1 ###

```
    public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
    {
        [NotMapped]
        public virtual ICollection<IdentityRole<string>> Roles { get; set; }
    }
```

Error:

```
Unhandled Exception: System.InvalidOperationException: The property 'Roles' is not a navigation property of entity type 'ApplicationUser'. The 'Include(string)' method can only be used with a '.' separated list of navigation property names.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can make a query that returns a list of users with roles or modify your current one to `Include` the roles like this:

```
users = _dbContext.Users
    .Include(u => u.Roles)
    .ToList();
```

Now in your Razor code you can do this:

```
@foreach(var user in @Model.users)
{
    foreach(var role in user.Roles)
    {
        <tr>@user.Name - @role.Name</tr>
    }
}
```

Note: Your HTML `table` code needs a little work as it doesn't have any `tr` or `th/td` elements

Comment: It fails on line: ".Include(u => u.Roles)". I am getting an error: "Cannot resolve symbol 'Roles'"

Comment: Oh yes, It's Identity Core... You may need to add the navigation property to your user class.

Comment: I added @page to the .cshtml, the using statement for ApplicationUser to my .cs-file, but it's still not working.

Comment: No, I mean to your `ApplicationUser` class, add a line something like this: `public virtual ICollection<Role> Roles { get; set; }`

Comment: I've added `public virtual ICollection<IdentityRole> Roles { get; set; }`, but it crashes and shows me the error: `Invalid column name 'ApplicationUserId'.`

Comment: Why did you add `NotMapped` attribute? Remove that.

Comment: Otherwise I keep getting the error mentioned earlier, about the invalid column name. `NotMapped` fixed this error but produced another one.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47767267/ef-core-2-how-to-include-roles-navigation-property-on-identityuser